# how to hold the state of an array of inputs with unknow length

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-state

so i want to store the state of an array with an unknown length.

so basically the user can choose between 2,3 or 4 players and then he will be asked to enter their names
the problem is that i couldn't find a way to store their names inside a value of a useState with an array type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can. Just destructure the previous value of the array and add in your new player.

```
setPlayer([...prevPlayers, newPlayer])
```

Comment: the problem is that i need the values to be in order so i can know the name of each player by index. for example the player 1 will have the name of the index 0 from the array

Comment: You will have to write a sorting algorithm to sort the players based on their id before setting the state. It has already been answered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value